# clarification on traceroute -T option

Tags: linux, tcp, traceroute

When using the -T option to use TCP SYN for probes, (1.)is this how it works: SYN is sent and ACK is received so only a two way handshake occurs so connection with server is made but no confirmation is sent back to server? and it still tracks the server address and data received through traceroute,(2.) is this what keeps the probes from being identified by server firewall/ applications?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: (1) You could use `tcpdump` to confirm what's being sent and received. (2) No, the fact that's it's TCP is what allows it through firewalls, which often block UDP and ICMP.